# .toFixed(2) not working?

Tags: jquery

Can someone please please enlighten me to as why my toFixed() isn't working?

```
$("#amount").blur(function() {
        if ($('#amount').val() % 100 != 0) {
        alert("must be a multiple of 100, please try again")
        } else {
        $('#fee').val(parseFloat($('#amount').val()) * .035).toFixed(2);
        }

        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$('#fee').val(parseFloat($('#amount').val() * .035).toFixed(2));
```

Rearranged the brackets

Comment: Brackets still aren't right.  `parseFloat($('#amount').val() * .035)` - you're running `parseFloat()` on the result of a calculation, which is already a number.  Depending on the input, the OP might be able to leave `parseFloat()` out altogether and allow the `*` operator to do the coercion.